# Edit: getting null value in a join statement if the value does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Edit: Thank you very much with all your helps but I may have not BOLD the problem about NULL values. Actually I want it to consider null values as well. cause there is no way to do calculation on null values.
I want it to add null value to before price column if it does not exit.
are there anyway for doing that? Thank you and sorry again.
Did not know I may run into this problem.

```
╔══════════╤════════════╤═══════════╤══════════════╗
║ store_id │ product_id │ now_price │ before_price ║
╠══════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╣
║ 1        │ 2          │ 20000     │ NULL         ║
╟──────────┼────────────┼───────────┼──────────────╢
║ 2        │ 2          │ 18000     │ 21000        ║
╟──────────┼────────────┼───────────┼──────────────╢
║ 3        │ 2          │ 10000     │ NULL         ║
╚══════════╧════════════╧═══════════╧══════════════╝
```

> I've got two tables for prices one of them is for now and one of them
>   is for before. the table structures are like this:
>
> now :
>
> ```
> ╔══════════╤════════════╤═══════╗
> ║ store_id │ product_id │ price ║
> ╠══════════╪════════════╪═══════╣
> ║ 1        │ 2          │ 20000 ║
> ╟──────────┼────────────┼───────╢
> ║ 2        │ 2          │ 30000 ║
> ╟──────────┼────────────┼───────╢
> ║ 3        │ 2          │ 25000 ║
> ╚══════════╧════════════╧═══════╝
> ```
>
> before :
>
> ```
> ╔══════════╤════════════╤═══════╗
> ║ store_id │ product_id │ price ║
> ╠══════════╪════════════╪═══════╣
> ║ 1        │ 2          │ 19800 ║
> ╟──────────┼────────────┼───────╢
> ║ 2        │ 2          │ 28000 ║
> ╟──────────┼────────────┼───────╢
> ║ 3        │ 2          │ 24300 ║
> ╚══════════╧════════════╧═══════╝
> ```
>
> now I want to have the the difference between the data in a table like
>   this :
>
> ```
> ╔══════════╤════════════╤════════════╗
> ║ store_id │ product_id │ difference ║
> ╠══════════╪════════════╪════════════╣
> ║ 1        │ 2          │ -200       ║
> ╟──────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
> ║ 2        │ 2          │ -2000      ║
> ╟──────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
> ║ 3        │ 2          │ -700       ║
> ╚══════════╧════════════╧════════════╝
> ```
>
> How can I do that? Thank you. and btw there maybe a product
>   unavailable in a store is it possible to maybe get a null value for
>   them?

Answer (score 1):

Inner join wiil be handy.

```
SELECT T1.`store_id`,
       T2.`product_id`,
      (T1.`price`-T2.`price`) AS Difference
    FROM
    price_now T2
    INNER JOIN 
    price_before T1 ON T1.`store_id` = T2.`store_id` AND T1.`product_id` = T2.`product_id`
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do basic math with SQL like so:

```
SELECT
    `a`.`store_id`,
    `a`.`product_id`,
    (`b`.`price` - `a`.`price`) AS `difference`
FROM `table1` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `b` ON `a`.`store_id` = `b`.`store_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple join

```
select store_id, product_id, b.price -a.price from table1 a join table2 b on a.store_id=b.store_id and a.product_id=b.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
select
  case when exists (select product_id from table1 a 
  join table2 b on  a.product_id = b.product_id)
  then (select store_id, product_id, (b.price - a.price) as difference 
  from table1 a 
  join table2 b on a.store_id = b.store_id 
  and a.product_id = b.product_id) 
  else null
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT now.store_id,now.product_id,now.price - before.price AS difference 
FROM now LEFT JOIN before ON now.store_id = before.store_id
```